# How to draw a Table in WPF Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have managed to draw a Table using(System.Windows.Documents) on a Flow Document panel in WPF but need to transfer the same code for the table and embed it in a Canvas panel instead of the Flow Document. However I am unable to do this and the error message I get is:

> cannot convert from System.Windows.Documents.Table" to System.Windows.UIElement"

Is there something else that can work as a table where I can interact with the table cells easily (need to check them for mouse events)? I need to switch to a canvas to be able to draw (in real time) a touchless cursor on the screen that moves over the table.

Comment: DataGrid? GridView? Have you looked into any of the normal WPF grid/table controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this into a `FlowDocument`, then place a [`FlowDocumentReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx) in the `Canvas`.  The `Table` (and other `Document` classes) are not derived from `UIElement`, and provide no visuals on their own.  The `FlowDocumentReader` creates the visual of the document, which can then be placed into any other container.

Comment: If I create the flowdocument within the canvas, can I also have a touchless cursor (a small circle) hovering over the table in the flow document mimicking my mouse pointer? Do I have to adjust the Z-indexes to achieve this?

Comment: Also, I get a similar error when adding the flow doc to the canvas. Error: "Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(System.Windows.UIElement)' has some invalid arguments"  Code used : myCanvas.Children.Add(flowDoc);

Comment: @DarthCoder Updated :) SOrry about that

Comment: I'm very new to this, can you also show me some code as to how to add the flow document (say flowdoc) to the Reader (say FlowReader) and then add it to a canvas?  Just the overview would help!

Comment: @DarthCoder It'd just be `<FlowDocumentReader><FlowDocument>...</FlowDocumentReader>`

Comment: I meant using C#, I am not using XAML to generate any of these document elements.

Comment: @DarthCoder Then just set the document property, and add the reader to your canvas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.document.aspx